# cpp:char(-1) in Java-char

Tags: java, c++

I have client-server app. Client on C++, server on Java.
I am sending byte-stream form client to server, and from server to client.
Tell me please, when I sent **char(-1)** from C++, what value equals to it in Java?
And what value I must sent from Java to C++, to get **char(-1)** in Cpp code?

Comment: If you write both the client and the server, why don't you just simply try it out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are writing through a byte stream, your `char(-1)` arrives as `255`, as byte streams normally transmit unsigned bytes.
The `-1` which is read when you read the end of a stream can not be send explicitely but only through closing the stream.

Comment: so char(-1) in Cpp is equals (byte)255 in Java?

Comment: As I said, you are using a byte stream, byte streams are unsigned, `-1` is binary encoded using 2s complement which equals ´0xff` or `255`. Java bytes are signed, so you get a `-1` back if you read it into a byte array, but all stream `read()` methods in Java return unsigned bytes, so you'll get `255`.

Answer (score 1):

There's no single answer; it depends on how C++ encodes the data and how Java interprets it. The most common encoding of `char(-1)` is the number 255. Note that this isn't defined by C++; a one's-complement system might encode it as 254. But also note that there are innumerable ways to encode data across the wire: Elias coding, various ASN.1 encodings, decimal digits, hex, etc.

At the Java end, even assuming a simple char-to-byte encoding, it depends on how you de-serialise the byte and into what type.

Comment: Now i am writing serializator from Java to Cpp, so I answer this question:)